# Не выводит массив и вылетает за границы - C#

Tags: c#

Собственно, не работает `MergeSorting` (точнее не выводит отсортированный массив: пробовал по разному - не получается (и в блочной выбивает (Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
Имя параметра: index)
в этом месте

```
buckets[bucketNumber].Add(value);
```

Весь код представлен ниже

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Variant2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Stopwatch stopWatch;
        int numb;
        double[] arr = null;
        double min, max;
        public Form1()
        {
            stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;
            numb = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            arr = new double[numb];
            Random rand = new Random();
            min = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            max = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = min + (max - min) * rand.NextDouble();
                richTextBox1.Text += arr[i] + "\r\n";
            }
        }
        public double[] BucketSort(double[] array)
        {
            List<List<double>> buckets = new List<List<double>>();
            InitializeBuckets(buckets);

            Scatter(array, buckets);

            int i = 0;
            foreach (List<double> bucket in buckets)
            {
                double[] arr1 = bucket.ToArray();
                InsertionSort(arr1);

                foreach (double d in arr)
                {
                    array[i++] = d;
                }
            }

            return array;
        }

        private void Scatter(double[] array, List<List<double>> buckets)
        {
            foreach (double value in array)
            {
                int bucketNumber = GetBucketNumber(value);
                buckets[bucketNumber].Add(value);
            }
        }

        private void InsertionSort(double[] array)
        {
            int j;
            double temp;

            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                j = i;
                while (j > 0 && array[j] < array[j - 1])
                {
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = temp;
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }

        private int GetBucketNumber(double value)
        {
            double val = value * 10;
            int bucketNumber = (int)Math.Floor(val);
            return bucketNumber;
        }

        private static void InitializeBuckets(List<List<double>> buckets)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                List<double> a = new List<double>();
                buckets.Add(a);
            }
        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                int da;
                double tmp;
                int ad = 1;
                for (ad = 1; ad < numb; ad++)
                {
                    da = ad;
                    while (da > 0 && arr[da - 1] > arr[da])
                    {
                        tmp = arr[da];
                        arr[da] = arr[da - 1];
                        arr[da - 1] = tmp;
                        da--;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Text += arr[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds);
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                QuickSorting.sorting(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
                for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Text += arr[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds);
            }
            if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < numb - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < numb; j++)
                    {
                        if (arr[i] > arr[j])
                        {
                            double b = arr[i];
                            arr[i] = arr[j];
                            arr[j] = b;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < numb; k++)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Text += arr[k] + "\r\n";
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds);
            }
            if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                MergeSorting.sort(arr);
                for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Text += arr[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds);
            }
            if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                double tmp;
                for (int i = 0; i < numb - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < numb; j++)
                    {
                        if (arr[i] > arr[j])
                        {
                            tmp = arr[i];
                            arr[i] = arr[j];
                            arr[j] = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Text += arr[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds);
            }
            if (radioButton6.Checked == true)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                double tmp;
                for (int i = 0; i < numb - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < numb; j++)
                    {
                        if (arr[i] < arr[j])
                        {
                            tmp = arr[i];
                            arr[i] = arr[j];
                            arr[j] = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Text += arr[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds);
            }
            if (radioButton7.Checked == true)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                PyramidSorting.sorting(arr, arr.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Text += arr[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds);
            }
            if (radioButton8.Checked == true)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                int j, i;
                double[] b = new double[numb];
                for (i = 0; i < numb; i++)
                {
                    int c = 0;
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                        if (arr[j] <= arr[i])
                            c++;
                    for (j = i + 1; j < numb; j++)
                        if (arr[j] < arr[i])
                            c++;
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < numb; k++)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Text += b[k] + "\r\n";
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds);
            }
            if (radioButton9.Checked == true)
            {
                stopWatch.Start();
                double[] arr1 = new double[numb];
                arr1 = BucketSort(arr);
                for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Text += arr[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                    ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                    ts.Milliseconds);
            }
        }

        public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label6.Text = "00:00:00.000";
            stopWatch.Reset();
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            richTextBox2.Clear();
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    public class MergeSorting
    {
        public static double[] sort(double[] arr)
        {
            if (arr.Length == 1)
                return arr;
            int mid_point = arr.Length / 2;
            return merge(sort(arr.Take(mid_point).ToArray()),         sort(arr.Skip(mid_point).ToArray()));
        }
        public static double[] merge(double[] mass1, double[] mass2)
        {
            int a = 0, b = 0;
            double[] merged = new double[mass1.Length + mass2.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < mass1.Length + mass2.Length; i++)
            {
                if (b < mass2.Length && a < mass1.Length)
                    if (mass1[a] > mass2[b] && b < mass2.Length)
                        merged[i] = mass2[b++];
                    else
                        merged[i] = mass1[a++];
                else
                    if (b < mass2.Length)
                        merged[i] = mass2[b++];
                    else
                        merged[i] = mass1[a++];
            }
            return merged;
        }
    }


    public class QuickSorting
    {
        public static void sorting(double[] arr, long first, long last)
        {
            double p = arr[(last - first) / 2 + first];
            double temp;
            long i = first, j = last;
            while (i <= j)
            {
                while (arr[i] < p && i <= last) ++i;
                while (arr[j] > p && j >= first) --j;
                if (i <= j)
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                    ++i; --j;
                }
            }
            if (j > first) sorting(arr, first, j);
            if (i < last) sorting(arr, i, last);
        }
    }
    class PyramidSorting
    {
        static int add2pyramid(double[] arr, int i, int N)
        {
            int imax;
            double buf;
            if ((2 * i + 2) < N)
            {
                if (arr[2 * i + 1] < arr[2 * i + 2]) imax = 2 * i + 2;
                else imax = 2 * i + 1;
            }
            else imax = 2 * i + 1;
            if (imax >= N) return i;
            if (arr[i] < arr[imax])
            {
                buf = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[imax];
                arr[imax] = buf;
                if (imax < N / 2) i = imax;
            }
            return i;
        }
        public static void sorting(double[] arr, int len)
        {
            for (int i = len / 2 - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                long prev_i = i;
                i = add2pyramid(arr, i, len);
                if (prev_i != i) ++i;
            }

            double buf;
            for (int k = len - 1; k > 0; --k)
            {
                buf = arr[0];
                arr[0] = arr[k];
                arr[k] = buf;
                int i = 0, prev_i = -1;
                while (i != prev_i)
                {
                    prev_i = i;
                    i = add2pyramid(arr, i, k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция `GetBucketNumber` не знает, сколько у вас всего bucket'ов, поэтому, понятно, индекс может выйти за границу диапазона.

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
int bucketNumber = (GetBucketNumber(value) & 0x7FFFFFFF) % buckets.Length;
buckets[bucketNumber].Add(value);
```

При этом код перестанет вылетать (но я не уверен, что он станет при этом *правильным*, я не разбирал его смысл).

Comment: Исправил, теперь говорит, что вылетаю за границы тут :
    foreach (double d in arr)
                {
                    array[i++] = d;
                }

Comment: @JIekT0P: Ну так это новая ошибка. Сколько у вас элементов выделено в `array`?